# brew uses /usr/bin/autom4te in stead of /usr/local/bin/autom4te

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to `brew` `weechat`, which has `p11-kit` as a dependency.

```
$ brew install p11-kit
==> Downloading http://p11-glue.freedesktop.org/releases/p11-kit-0.18.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/p11-kit-0.18.1.tar.gz
==> Patching
patching file configure.ac
patching file configure
Hunk #1 succeeded at 17201 with fuzz 1.
patching file common/library.c
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/p11-kit/0.18.1 --without-trust-paths
==> make
     You might want to install the Automake and Perl packages.
     Grab them from any GNU archive site.
Can't locate Autom4te/C4che.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/share/autoconf /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.12 /Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.12 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.4 /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.12 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12 .) at /usr/bin/autom4te line 39.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/autom4te line 39.
make: *** [configure] Error 1
```

I tried force linking autoconf

```
$ which autom4te
/usr/bin/autom4te
$ brew link --force autoconf
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69... 18 symlinks created
$ which autom4te
/usr/local/bin/autom4te
```

No dice. I keep getting the error from `/usr/bin/autom4te`
Am I missing something?

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: I've opened an issue here https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/20586

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and renamed the files `autoconf`, `autoheader`, `autom4te`, `autoreconf`, `autoscan`, `autoupdate` and `ifnames` in `/usr/bin` to force my machine to use the ones made available in `/usr/local/bin` after a `brew link --force autoconf`.

Brewing worked without an issue.

I don't know where the files in `/usr/bin/` came from or if I borked things up bad by doing this. I'm keeping the renamed files in place, just in case I ever remember what I did today when things start to stink.

(see https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/20586 for more troubleshooting)

Comment: These files are from Apples's Xcode and removing them is not a good idea.

Comment: I ran `brew link --overwrite autoconf`. Worked for me perfectly on macOS Catalina.